# Difference of potential between points

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

I have the following question: What is the potential difference between point A - B?
[image]

Could somebody please explain me how should I count it? The voltage U=18V. I found out that V1=8V, V2=10V, V3=10V, V4=8V. The answer is -2V.

Comment: Hi Maciej, welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: It seems you are on the right track. As drawn and stated, it is unclear to me whether 2 or -2 would be the correct answer as the polarity at U is not given (one might deduce it from the direction in which the current was drawn - not clear if that is you, or the original). Is there an actual conceptual problem you would like help with? If there is, and you state it explicitly, then this question becomes "answerable" under the policies of this site.

Comment: I draw those arrows(they shouldn't be there). So the polarity at U is not given. My problem is how should I know in which direction current flows in the example above, because as @Floris stated it would be then possible to know should it be -2 or 2. Or is it deducible somehow? I'm very sorry if I have violated rules of stackexchange :(

Comment: If the only information you have is what was given, then either polarity would be a valid response. I suggest you update your question - no need to apologize, you are new here and we want to help you learn how to navigate this site!

Comment: I understand know that it is just a mistake in the exercise. Thank you very much @Floris.

Comment: You're welcome- and do come back with more questions (and answers...)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each branch containing resistors acts as a potential divider, dividing the voltage across the whole branch in the ratios 40:50 and 50:40 (top and bottom respectively), ie the ratios 4:5 and 5:4. This means that each resistor will have either 4/(4+5)=4/9 or 5/(4+5) = 5/9 of the total voltage (18V), which as you have correctly calculated is 8V for both the 40ohm resistors and 10V for the 50ohm resistors. If we use the left hand edge of the circuit as our 0V line, then point A will have a potential of 8V, and point B will have a potential of 10V, so a difference of 2V between them. It could also be -2V as there is no way given this diagram to determine which way the current flows.